# pandas: while loop to simultaneously advance through multiple lists and call functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, while-loop

I want my code to:

- read data from a CSV and make a dataframe: "source_df"
- see if the dataframe contains any columns specified in a list:
  "possible_columns"
- call a unique function to replace the values in each column whose header is found in the "possible_columns" the list, then insert the modified values in a new dataframe: "destination_df"

Here it is:

```
import pandas as pd

#creates source_df
file = "yes-no-true-false.csv"
data = pd.read_csv(file)
source_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#creates destination_df
blanklist = []
destination_df = pd.DataFrame(blanklist)

#create the column header lists for comparison in the while loop
columns = source_df.head(0)
possible_columns = ['yes/no','true/false']

#establish the functions list and define the functions to replace column values
fix_functions_list = ['yes_no_fix()','true_false_fix()']

def yes_no_fix():
    destination_df['yes/no'] = destination_df['yes/no fixed'].replace("No","0").replace("Yes","1")
def true_false_fix():
    destination_df['true/false'] = destination_df['true/false fixed'].replace('False', '1').replace('True', '0')


'''use the counter to call a unique function from the function list to replace the values in each column whose header is found in the "possible_columns" the list, insert the modified values in "destination_df, then advance the counter'''

counter = 0
while counter < len(possible_columns):
    if possible_columns[counter] in columns:
        destination_df.insert(counter, possible_columns[counter], source_df[possible_columns[counter]])
        fix_functions_list[counter]
        counter = counter + 1

#see if it works
print(destination_df.head(10))
```

When I print(destination_df), I see the unmodified column values from source_df. When I call the functions independently they work, which makes me think something is going wrong in my while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are trying to call a function that is stored in a list as a string.

```
fix_functions_list[cnt]
```

This will not actually run the function just access the string value.
I would try and find another way to run these functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
def yes_no_fix():
    destination_df['yes/no'] = destination_df['yes/no fixed'].replace("No","0").replace("Yes","1")
def true_false_fix():
    destination_df['true/false'] = destination_df['true/false fixed'].replace('False', '1').replace('True', '0')

fix_functions_list = {0:yes_no_fix,1:true_false_fix}
```

and change the function calling to like below

```
fix_functions_list[counter]()
```

Comment: These are exactly the type of simple edits I was hoping for. However, when I try them, I get a "KeyError: 3" which says there is a problem in the fix_functions_list[counter](). Thoughts?

Comment: move the counter from inside of if condition and add after if condition

Comment: what you are doing is you are incrementing the counter even when there is no match

Comment: please see the below answer,  let me know if you get any errors. if it runs without errors, you will get the required answer.

Comment: when I move the counter update to outside the IF condition, I still get the KeyError

Answer (score 0):

```
#creates source_df
file = "yes-no-true-false.csv"
data = pd.read_csv(file)
source_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

possible_columns = ['yes/no','true/false']
mapping_dict={'yes/no':{"No":"0","Yes":"1"} ,'true/false': {'False':'1','True': '0'}
old_columns=[if column not in possible_columns for column in source_df.columns]
existed_columns=[if column in possible_columns  for column in source_df.columns]
new_df=source_df[existed_columns]
for column in new_df.columns:
    new_df[column].map(mapping_dict[column])

new_df[old_columns]=source_df[old_columns]
```

Comment: Thank you for this example. However, the code I posted was a simplified example. In reality,  the dataset I will be working with will have 25+ columns with up to 15 variables each, so the mapping_dict idea seems like it would be difficult to write.